# How to stop random effect in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

hey guys i am using [Codecanyon](http://codecanyon.net/item/magicwall-responsive-image-grid/full_screen_preview/7391534) for my image gallery. Right now it is animating images with random effect. i want to remove random effect. any suggestion how can i do this. below is the functions of animation.

```
parseAnimationOptions: function (t) {
        var i, o = this,
            n = ["flipX", "flipY", "rollInX", "rollInY", "rollOutX", "rollOutY", "slideX", "slideY", "slideRow", "slideColumn", "fade"];
        return t.animation ? i = t.animation : "*" == o.options.animations ? (i = o.excludeAnimations(n),
         i = (Math.random() < .5 ? "" : "-") + i[Math.floor(Math.random() * i.length)]) : (o.selectedAnimations && o.selectedAnimations.length || (o.selectedAnimations = o.options.animations.split(":")),
          i = o.excludeAnimations("*" == o.selectedAnimations[0] ? n : o.selectedAnimations[0].split(",")),
          i = i[Math.floor(Math.random() * i.length)],
           o.selectedAnimations.splice(0, 1)), -1 == n.indexOf(i.replace("-", "")) && (i = "fade"), e.extend(!0, t, {
            animation: i,
            type: i.replace(/[XY-]/g, ""),
            dir: 0 == i.indexOf("-", 0) ? -1 : 1,
            axis: i.replace(/[^XY]/g, ""),
            duration: t.duration || o.options[i.replace("-", "") + "Duration"] || o.options.duration,
            easing: t.easing || o.options[i.replace("-", "") + "Easing"] || o.options.easing
        })
    }
```

and this code is on the page

```
$(".magicwall").magicWall({
            maxItemWidth: 300,
            maxItemHeight: 240,
            animations: "rollOutY",
            flipXDuration: 500,

        });
```

Comment: Remove Math.random function wherever it is used... Use appropriate logic over there

Comment: i tried its not working

Comment: It looks like you set all parameters correctly. I'm not sure but try to set 'animation' option by array with single needed item 'rollOutY'.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing wrong in your arrangement of code, but I've put together a demo on jsfiddle using the latest magicwall code and a similar jQuery snippet to yours, and all seems to work as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/Fac79/

Answer (score 0):

From these resouce: http://teefouad.com/plugins/magicwall/demo15-public-methods.html
Button "FlipX animation only"

```
$(".btn.flipx").click(function(){
    $(".magicwall").magicWall("option", "animations", "flipX,-flipX");
});
```

So you should try:

```
$(".magicwall").magicWall({
      maxItemWidth: 300,
      maxItemHeight: 240,
      animations: "rollOutY,-rollOutY",
      flipXDuration: 500,
});
```

I don't have script so I can't test this. Let's tell me your result.